# UserName profile property not updated after migration

Tags: 2010, user-profile, active-directory, migration

I am working for the support of a SharePoint 2010 intranet.
The User Profile Application Service performs an incremental synchronization each day.
The UPAS retrieves user profiles from an Active Directory.
Each SharePoint user profile has several properties and one of them is UserName.
The UserName property is mapped to the sAMAccountName AD property.

Active Directory user accounts will be migrated soon.
Some tests are performed in a preproduction environment to check users can still use the SP intranet after migration.

I have asked an AD administrator to migrate one AD user account for a test.
The administrator has created the new user account in AD and he has deactivated the old user account.
Old user account's sAMAccountName : sharept2
New user account's sAMAccountName : TestUser2.Sharepoint

The AD administrator has also migrated the corresponding SP user by executing the stsadm command with the migrateuser option.

An UPAS incremental synchronization has been run.
I have looked at the properties of the SP user profile.
The UserName property is still valued with : sharept2
I expect the UserName property to be valued with : TestUser2.Sharepoint

Why the UserName property has not been updated ?
What do I need to do to solve my issue ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it to resolve sAMAccountName changes:

run an incremental update to ensure the change has been picked up

stsadm -o migrateuser to merge old account into new with the -ignoresidhistory flag

Have a powershell script that iterates through all sites removing the old user account, remove-spuser

run audience compilation

Comment: I do not really understand the utility of the stsadm command. What do you mean exactly by merging the old account into the new one ?

Comment: when an account is renamed, SP will see them as 2 separate accounts, running the migrateuser merges the new account information into the old account so that data and permissions are not lost, the powershell equivelant is move-spuser.